# Indefinite article before country name

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles, toponyms

> We all wish for a Nigeria that provides and takes care of this countrymen.

Is the indefinite article grammatical?

Comment: are you referring to the use of 'a' in front of Nigeria?

Comment: I think you'd be more comfortable posting this to English Language Learners. But, I would recommend doing some research first and identifying a specific area of concern.

Answer (score 5):

The Nigeria the writer is talking about is not the Nigeria which exists today. It is a wished-for, hypothetical Nigeria; one of many possible ones. Hence, the use of the indefinite article is appropriate.

It should be 'We all wish for a Nigeria that provides and takes care of its citizens.' (You could use countrymen, but citizens is more inclusive).

It's the same format that Shakespeare uses when he has Shylock refer to the lawyer acting in the case which occurs towards the end of the Merchant of Venice as '[a Daniel come to judgement](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/108150.html)'.